# How to preserve trailing whitespace in bash function arguments?

Tags: bash, function, whitespace

Consider the following bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
  echo -n $1
  echo $2
}

foo 'Testing... ' 'OK' # => Testing...OK
# Whitespace --^                      ^
# Missing whitespace -----------------^
```

What happened to the trailing whitespace in the first argument?  How can preserve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. > What happened to the trailing whitespace in the first argument?

   The whitespace was included on the `echo` command line, but was discarded by the shell, the same as if you had typed:

   ```
   echo -n Testing... 
                     ^
                     |----- there is a space here
   ```
2. > How can preserve it?

   Quote your variables:

   ```
   function foo {
     echo -n "$1"
     echo "$2"
   }
   ```

Comment: It's so obvious now that I see it.  I feel silly =D